# How to run "git blame" on a given set of files using Octokit

Tags: ruby, git, blame, octokit, git-blame

I'm pretty new to the Ruby world and I'm working on a legacy ruby script that uses Octokit to which I need to add the support for running "git blame" command on a bunch of files to figure out the developers involved in causing conflicts.

I went through the documentation of Octokit - https://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Client/Labels.html - but I can't seem to find a way to run git blame using Octokit. Can someone please provide me some guidance of how I should go about this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need to use Octokit for this? Ruby lets you execute arbitrary shell commands using backticks.

Comment: Octokit doesn't seem to provide blame interface. However, you might be interested in using Github GraphQL for this: https://github.community/t/retrieve-git-blame-data-using-the-github-graphql-api/149919